# Structure map - understanding Use and Add semantics

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have the following code with NServiceBus & StructureMap 2.6.2 wired up together:

```
var bus = Configure.WithWeb().StructureMapBuilder(container)
ObjectFactory.Container.Configure(r => 
    r.For<IBus>().Singleton().Use(Configure.Instance.CreateBus().Start())
);

container.Configure(r => r.For<IBus>().Singleton().Add<MyBus>().Named("named"));
```

I want first registration to be a default one, second registration to be available as a named one. But when I run:

```
var bus1 = container.GetInstance<IBus>();
var bus2 = container.GetInstance<IBus>("named");
```

I get both instances of type MyBus. According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792922/named-instances-and-a-default-instance-in-structuremap) first instance must come from first registration (of type UnicastBus) but it is not.

Am I understanding Use and Add semantics wrong?

Comment: What version of StructureMap are you using. It is possible the behavior changed between 2.x and 3.x. It is also possible that the change in behavior was unintended and this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You are registering the first instance in the `ObjectFactory` container instance. The second instance is being registered in a local container instance named `container`.

For this behavior to work right, you need to use the same container instance for both registrations.

On a side note, you should never use the `ObjectFactory` static instance (as per the [documentation](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/)).

> The static ObjectFactory wrapper for Container is still available in 3.0, but we strongly recommend against using it for new applications. It only exists for easier compatibility with older installations.

Comment: Probably close, but it is not the case. I've tried all ObjectFactory.Container and stack parameter container, still Add registration overrides previous Use registration when resolving default not-named instance.

Answer (score 1):

Both registrations:

```
ObjectFactory.Container.Configure(r => 
    r.For<IBus>().Singleton().Use(Configure.Instance.CreateBus().Start())
);
```

and

```
container.Configure(r => r.For<IBus>().Singleton().Add<MyBus>().Named("named"));
```

are applied do different instances of container (container != ObjectFactory.Container). This results in `container` having only one registration of `IBus` (`MyBus`) and that is why you can only resolve this dependency. When you register only one type (even if it is named instance) for specific plugin type you are able to resolve it when using `container.GetInstance<TPluginType>()`. To fix this issue and have expected behavior you need to change this registration:

```
ObjectFactory.Container.Configure(r => 
    r.For<IBus>().Singleton().Use(Configure.Instance.CreateBus().Start())
);
```

with this:

```
container.Configure(r => 
    r.For<IBus>().Singleton().Use(Configure.Instance.CreateBus().Start())
);
```

Tested this issue in both versions of SM (2.6 and 3+) and the behavior is the same on these versions.

Hope this helps!